# Problem Mounting EFS through .ebextensions on EB using Linux 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-efs, amazon-linux-2

We have a .war, containing an .ebextensions folder with the [storage-efs-mountfilesystem.config](https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/instance-configuration/storage-efs-mountfilesystem.config), which mounts the efs to the EC2 Instance. On Linux 1 it works like a charm. Now we use the same war on Linux 2 and cannot deploy it, as we get an error which says command execution failed. We got the .config from AWS' [developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/services-efs.html) so we dont know if it just is not updated for Linux 2 or we have to change something, not mentioned on the docs?

Here are the logs:

> 2022-03-25 09:43:56,732 [ERROR] Command 01_mount (/tmp/mount-efs.sh) failed
> 2022-03-25 09:43:56,732 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of prebuild_0_Kiwi: Command
> 01_mount failed
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 576, in run_config
> CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 276, in build
> self._config.commands)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
> raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
> cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 01_mount failed
> 2022-03-25 09:43:56,733 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
> 2022-03-25 09:43:56,733 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command 01_mount failed
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 176, in 
> worklog.build(metadata, configSets)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 137, in build
> Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 564, in build
> self.run_config(config, worklog)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 576, in run_config
> CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 276, in build
> self._config.commands)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
> raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
> cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 01_mount failed

Answer (score 0):

For me this did helped create a config file which is executed before the mount file:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    MOUNT_UID: 3984
    MOUNT_GID: 3984
```

To Create the filesystem I used this configuration (Which adds a accesspoint) and configures access from the VPC group

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:customoption:
    VPCId: "vpc-00000000000000000"
    VpcDefaultGroupId: 'sg-00000000000000000'
## Subnet Options
    SubnetA: "subnet-00000000000000000"
    SubnetB: "subnet-00000000000000000"
    SubnetC: "subnet-00000000000000000"

Resources:
  FileSystem:
    Type: AWS::EFS::FileSystem
    Properties:
      FileSystemTags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: "EB-EFS-FileSystem"
      PerformanceMode: "generalPurpose"
      Encrypted: "false"
#      KmsKeyId: "KMS-key-ARN"

  AccessPoint:
    Type: AWS::EFS::AccessPoint
    Properties: 
        AccessPointTags: 
        - Key: Name
          Value: "EB-EFS-AccessPoint"
        FileSystemId: {Ref: FileSystem}

## Mount Target Resources
  MountTargetA:
    Type: AWS::EFS::MountTarget
    Properties:
      FileSystemId: {Ref: FileSystem}
      SecurityGroups:
      - {Ref: MountTargetSecurityGroup}
      SubnetId:
        Fn::GetOptionSetting: {OptionName: SubnetA}
  MountTargetB:
    Type: AWS::EFS::MountTarget
    Properties:
      FileSystemId: {Ref: FileSystem}
      SecurityGroups:
      - {Ref: MountTargetSecurityGroup}
      SubnetId:
        Fn::GetOptionSetting: {OptionName: SubnetB}
  MountTargetC:
    Type: AWS::EFS::MountTarget
    Properties:
      FileSystemId: {Ref: FileSystem}
      SecurityGroups:
      - {Ref: MountTargetSecurityGroup}
      SubnetId:
        Fn::GetOptionSetting: {OptionName: SubnetC}

##############################################
#### Do not modify values below this line ####
##############################################

  MountTargetSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security group for mount target
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - FromPort: '2049'
        IpProtocol: tcp
        SourceSecurityGroupId:
          Fn::GetAtt: [AWSEBSecurityGroup, GroupId]
        ToPort: '2049'
      - FromPort: '2049'
        IpProtocol: tcp
        SourceSecurityGroupId: 
          Fn::GetOptionSetting: {OptionName: VpcDefaultGroupId} 
        ToPort: '2049'
      VpcId:
        Fn::GetOptionSetting: {OptionName: VPCId}
```